# Aggregating data in R using group by and keeping values of other columns that are not NA

Tags: r, sorting, group-by, aggregate

I wonder if someone can help out. I have the following dataset where an ID is a company that has hired different number people over time with ID duplicates. And we have the address of IDs but it is not collected for each row:

```
ID      Address        Number of hiring
1                             5
2       Montreal              2 
3                             3
4       Helsinki              4 
1       London                1
2                             3
3       Dubai                 5
```

and I'd like to **group by** ID and add a column that shows the total number of hiring cities that an ID has hired to as well as a column showing the address ID. When I do it, because there are missing values in address, R automatically selects the first row for each ID that may have missing value. So, the following should be the result:

```
ID      Address         Total Number of hiring
1       London                6
2       Montreal              5 
3       Dubai                 8
4       Helsinki              4
```

I am trying to use the **dplyr** in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the first non-empty `Address` for each `ID` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Address = Address[Address != ''][1],
            total_hiring = sum(Number_of_hiring, na.rm  =TRUE))

#     ID Address  total_hiring
#  <int> <chr>           <int>
#1     1 London              6
#2     2 Montreal            5
#3     3 Dubai               8
#4     4 Helsinki            4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Address = c("", 
"Montreal", "", "Helsinki", "London", "", "Dubai"), Number_of_hiring = c(5L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```